# Dynamic UI Generation - Java

Tags: java, swing, layout, netbeans

[image: Problem Steps]

Hi,

I have a requirement where the UI has to be dynamically generated. Please see the above image. Step 1 consists of a Dialog with a jcombobox and and jbutton. When I click the "+" button in step 1, a new row should get dynamically added to the jdialog, this is shown in Step 2. Similarly, more rows can be added using the "+" button. Pressing the "-" button should remove the row. Also, the JDialog should have a vertical scroll bar when necessary. I have been trying Grid layout but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [link](http://java2everyone.blogspot.com/2008/12/add-component-on-jframe-during-runtime.html) on how to add components on runtime and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468844/java-swing-add-remove-jbuttons-on-runtime) has an example to add/ remove jbuttons on runtime

Comment: Ok. I was adding the components but not calling the validate and revalidate methods on the dialog and frame respectively. The first link did the trick. Thanks O.D

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your UI should use a JScrollPane to be able to scroll when necessary...
I can't understand why GridLayout is not avilable , what is your error ? Did you do the correct import in your code ?
Could you give us more details

Jerome

Comment: Guesses and questions should be saved for comments.

Comment: It is available, but the new components being added were getting squeezed into the panel area and the panel size was not increasing. The validate and revalidate methods did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a `JScrollPane` from the start. Luckily for you `JScrollPane` allows to automatically show/hide the scrollbars when they are (not) needed. See the [`JScrollPane#set*ScrollBarPolicy`](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/formsdemo/index.html).

For your panel you will have to use a layout which allows to add components dynamically, like for example a `FlowLayout`. A non-core Java layout which can also be used for this case is the [JGoodies `FormLayout`](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/formsdemo/index.html) with a dynamic row builder. This `FormLayout` will easily allow to keep those columns used in your screenshot while allowing to dynamically add rows at runtime.