# Deleting all buttons dynamically

Tags: java, swing

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3468914/960086) to add buttons to my GUI dynamically and expected to be able to remove all of them too. To my understanding I am getting all the keys in the HashMap (strings) and then I am doing a for loop over the keys, and deleting them from the hashmap (getting the object back which I will delete). Problem is that after deleting the first button from the hashmap, the loop doesn't continue and my application crashes.

```
HashMap<String, JButton> buttonCache = new HashMap<>();
Set<String> names = buttonCache.keySet();
    /*
     * Checking which buttons exist in the hashmap
    */
    for (String name0 : names) {
        System.out.println("Name0: " + name0);
    }

    for (String name1 : names) {
        System.out.println("before removing: " + name1);
        buttonCache.containsKey(name1); //making sure its in it.
        JButton b = buttonCache.remove(name1);
        System.out.println("after removing: " + name1);
        //visualUI.remove(b); //not tested yet
    }
    //visualUI.invalidate();  //not tested yet
    //visualUI.repaint();     //not tested yet
```

The output is:

```
Name0: Cancel
Name0: Continue
2
before removing: Cancel
true
after removing: Cancel
```

Comment: If the keyset is linked to the HashMap you probably get a ConcurrentModification exception. In this case just copy the set and iterate over the copied set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete from a HashMap you need to delete with the help of the iterator.
See [Calling remove in foreach loop in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196586/calling-remove-in-foreach-loop-in-java).

EDIT: As per OP...

```
Iterator<String> it = names.iterator(); 
while(it.hasNext()) { 
  System.out.println(names); 
  String buttonName = it.next(); 
  JButton b = buttonCache.get(buttonName); 
  it.remove(); 
} 
System.out.println(names);
```

Comment: I did just tried with an iterator and had the same result. Let me try again, and confirm with the code.

Comment: @Juan also try commenting out the visualUI.remove(b); line. I am not sure what this does but that will tell you if your problem is in there. Also try posting the exception you get.

Comment: Okay, I think that with a little shuffling I manage to do it. You can add this code to your answer if you want: Iterator<String> it = names.iterator();    
        while(it.hasNext()) {  
            System.out.println(names);
            String buttonName = it.next();
            JButton b = buttonCache.get(buttonName);
            it.remove();
        }
        System.out.println(names);

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.  When you remove the button from the Hashmap it maybe still be found in UI and doesn't have any reference anymore. Maybe thats one Problem. I see commented lines that should take care of removing the buttons from the UI in your snippit - I guess you should let them do that and see what happens then.