# How do I make the user add JButtons?

Tags: jbutton

I want the user to be able to add or remove as many `JButtons` in a given `JPanel`. I want the buttons added by the user to be customizable as well, such as changing the color or the text of it. What's the best way to go about this? I've never done it before and im still pretty new to programming so keep it as english as possible thanks

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468844/java-swing-add-remove-jbuttons-on-runtime)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Swing add/remove jButtons on runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468844/java-swing-add-remove-jbuttons-on-runtime)